# Sign up button clicked function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftyuserdefaults

```
user.signUpInBackground{ (success: Bool, error:Error?) in
    if success{
        print("signed up")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(user.username, forKey: "username")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        user.signUpInBackground {(success: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if success {
                print("signed up")
                AVUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: user.username!, password: user.password!, block: {(user: AVUser?, error: Error?) in
                    if let user = user {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(user.username, forKey: "username")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                        appDelegate.login()
                    }
                })
            }else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am writing an app just like Instagram. This is a part of code when people click sign in button. I found it is quite difficult to understand.
Why `UserDefaults.standard` and `if success`repeat in the above code ? 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You are unable to understand an app you are making?

Comment: user.signUpInBackground is called twice, this doesn't looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you trying like this .. what is the issue? :

```
 user.signUpInBackground {(success: Bool, error: Error?) in
                if success {
                    print("signed up")
                    AVUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: user.username!, password: user.password!, block: {(user: AVUser?, error: Error?) in
                        if let user = user {
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(user.username, forKey: "username")
                            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                            let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                            appDelegate.login()
                        }
                    })
                }else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
```

i seem `user.signUpInBackground` method called two time . so `UserDefaults.standard` success repeat

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for your help. I made a stupid mistake. What really confuse me is that the wrong code also works and runs well.